# .htaccess redirect to php file

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

because .htacces including the syntax are totally new territory for me, I currently don't know how to create a specific redirect. I have given the following link:

```
www.example.com/RANDOM_STRING
```

This link should redirect via .htaccess to a PHP file where RANDOM_STRING is saved into a GET Parameter. Roughly speaking, it should be redirected something like this:

```
www.example.com/RANDOM_STRING > www.example.com/router.php?link=RANDOM_STRING
```

Is it even possible to redirect something like this via htaccess?

Thx

Comment: Yes it's quite possible. Have you searched the SO archives on "htaccess redirect" yet? You're more likely to get answers if you show your own effort and explain where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect `/router.php/?link=RANDOM_STRING` to `/router/` you can try something like the following near the top of your **.htaccess** file (using mod_rewrite):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^link=
RewriteRule ^link/$ /link/? [R,L]
```